# Trying to scrape image and I get empty output

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to scrape Twitter account image, I tried multiple ways and the output keeps give me empty list!

My Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = requests.get('https://twitter.com/jack/photo')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
image = soup.find_all('img')

print(image)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

That's a part of my project .. I tried lxml and find by class, but I still get nothing, maybe I'm missing something there but I don't know what it is.
If anyone can help me with it, I will be so appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The twitter is using some kind of frontend framework. I checked there is no img tag at all when you view the source of the page. Try to use selenium

Comment: Yes, I it works with selenium, but I want it with BeautifulSoup or lxml or scrapy, But not selenium, cause I want to host the project to HeroKu, and selenium doesn't go well with HeroKu.

Answer (score 0):

I can see some React being used in the page. If you open the page and inspect the elements, you will see that as soon as you click on the photo to enlarge it, a new div appears as if from thin air. Which implies that that get created by react.

In order to address this you will need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to open the page in a `virtual browser`, let the JavaScript do its magic and then look for the `img` tag.

Comment: Yeah, I tried selenium and it works fine, but I want it with BeautifulSoup or lxml or any other scraping library, I don't want to use selenium cause it doesn't work well with HeroKu ( I want to host my project in the end )

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you can find out where and how the web page pulls down the images from (say if it has some form of API that it hits to get the images), you will need the JS to render the page for you which will mean using something like Selenium.

Comment: There might be some other ways around it as expressed by the other response.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to scrape the path for JavaScript twitter.  If you examine the response of your page you will see the following snippit.

```
    <form action="https://mobile.twitter.com/i/nojs_router?path=%2Fjack%2Fphoto" method="POST" style="background-color: #fff; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 9999;">
  <div style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 24px; margin: 10%; width: 80%;">
    <p>We've detected that JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Would you like to proceed to legacy Twitter?</p>
    <p style="margin: 20px 0;">
      <button type="submit" style="background-color: #1da1f2; border-radius: 100px; border: none; box-shadow: none; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px; padding: 6px 16px;">Yes</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I would recommend disabling javascript in your browser and then figuring out how to view the photos like that.  Then you could mimic those requests using requests.

What worked for me was sendind a request to the path:
https://mobile.twitter.com/jack

Then using the css selector: class = "avatar".  There should be one child, an image tag, grab the src of that image tag and that should be the link to your photo.

As requested, here is the python code I used:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get('https://mobile.twitter.com/jack')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

avatars = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "avatar"})

print(avatars[0].findAll('img')[0].get('src'))
```

Note: Twitter changes their layout frequently, so this may not work for long.

Comment: Thank u so much, I changed the link and wrote that`image = soup.find_all('div', {"class: css-9pa8cd"})
print(image)` and still empty list, Honestly I don't know how to use css selector and how to intract with BeautifulSoup genrally, can you show me your code or explain how I can get it?